# @types/node/index.d.ts(6208,55): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map' 'Set' 'Symbol' 'WeakMap' 'WeakSet'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've been having this errors. I already add lib and target as "ES2018" and doesn't work. This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "module": "commonjs",
       "noImplicitAny": true,
       "removeComments": true,
       "preserveConstEnums": true,
       "declarationMap": true,
       "lib":"es2018",
       "target": "esnext",
       "allowJs": true
   },
   "files": [
       "core.ts",
       "sys.ts",
       "types.ts",
       "scanner.ts",
       "parser.ts",
       "utilities.ts",
       "binder.ts",
       "checker.ts",
       "emitter.ts",
       "program.ts",
       "commandLineParser.ts",
       "tsc.ts",
       "diagnosticInformationMap.generated.ts"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the same issue.

My problem was in incorrect calling tsc like here:

```
  "start": "node_modules/.bin/tsc index.ts --watch"
```

So I changed tsconfig to include only entry point

```
"include": [
    "src/index.ts"
  ],
```

And command to:

```
"start": "node_modules/.bin/tsc --watch"
```

All becomes perfect.